# How do I improve my "Skyfall" question for reopening?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, editing

> The question ["Critical reception of "Skyfall"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/122112/critical-reception-of-skyfall) is closed as opinion-based. Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question.

I am really angry that I have edited this three times, and none of the edits were successful in reopening the question. The latest comment says:

> Your latest edit hasn't made things less broad. There are thousands of critic reviews of the film, some positive and some negative. Do you want us to copy and paste these for you?

I have replied to the comment, but I have not gotten any response.

Any chance this could be reviewed for editing? What is something more specific I can ask about "Skyfall"?

I asked this question on January 29, when the Movies & TV site was "Today's Featured Site".

Comment: Can we see the contents of that original question? Not even the question's title (and probably the condensed version of the main question) can't be retraced.

Comment: @Joachim According to [an external website]( https://cilovers.com/skyfall-a-film-elevated-by-its-cinematography/),

> One of the key elements of Skyfall’s cinematography is its use of color. Throughout the film, Deakins uses color to create a sense of mood and atmosphere, with warm, golden hues used to evoke feelings of nostalgia and comfort and cold, blue tones used to create a sense of danger and foreboding.

How did "Skyfall" end up using color for mood and atmosphere?

Comment: This seems to be a common pattern of your activity across the network. It doesn't appear that you understand what Stack Exchange is for, in terms of desired and accepted content, nor how curation works, in terms of voting and reviews and closure/deletion. That your content is receiving the same result here as it did on multiple other sites (including one where it has resulted in your suspension) strongly suggests your anger is misdirected at best.

Comment: "including one where it has resulted in your suspension". You mean to say the 3D Printing site? How do you know about the 3D Printing site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am really angry

I'm sorry that this has been your first experience of the site, but with
respect you are not really taking the feedback about your question seriously. The people you are expressing anger towards are those
trying to explain why the question isn't suitable here.

The questions you have asked in various edits of your post are very very broad, and not suitable for this site, which is intended to be for answering focused specific questions

We are not a great site for providing you with a dissertation on the cinematography of Skyfall, or an in-depth summary of all criticism of the movie.

Have a look through the site and see the kinds of questions that are well received here.

> Any chance this could be reviewed for editing?

People are reviewing it and they are not voting for it to be re-opened.  Please take that for what it indicates.

> What is something less (sic) specific I can ask about "Skyfall"?

You seem to be suggesting that we provide you with topics to ask questions about Skyfall.  That is strange to me .... watch the movie and ask questions about things you don't understand or want to know more about.

**Question Deletion**

You have probably noticed that the question has been deleted.  This is because in its current state, it is overwhelmingly copied content from the
page you linked to.  This is copyright infringement, and unless you are the
owner of the copyright of that content, you can't copy verbatim all that text into your post.  If you edit it to remove that or replace it with your own original work, then I will undelete it (but not open it).

I appreciate that by linking to it, you are giving attribution to
the author of the content, however having the vast majority of your post copied from that page certainly does not constitute "fair use".